# HTTP to HTTPS redirect - Nginx vs Node Express

Tags: node.js, http, express, nginx

I want to redirect the HTTP traffic to the secure HTTPS version of my website. I am running NodeJS Express on an nginx server. What would be the best way to do the redirect: using nginx or Express? Is there any significant difference between the two options, like performance for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how you do it but the performance difference will likely be insignificant. What I usually do is when nginx handles the SSL keys and certificates then I also let it take care of the redirects. That way the Node app doesn't even need to know about the HTTP - all it cares is serving the requests coming from the reverse proxy.

Example nginx config:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name example.com;
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=3600";
            root /www/example.com/html;
            index index.html index.htm;

            location / {
                    return 302 https://example.com$request_uri;
            }
    }
```

Keep in mind that you will need to temporarily turn off the redirect to HTTPS if you're using Let's Encrypt but only for the time of certification renewal - something worth noting because it can be hard to diagnose when your certification renewal fails.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. I am indeed using Let's Encrypt, so I'm thinking about using the Node option to save myself and my colleagues the trouble of remembering to disable it on renewal, especially if there is no significant performance difference as you state.

Comment: Also, is there any reason to use a 302 status code instead of 301 (or 308)?

Comment: @DuncanLuk You can use 301 if you need permanent redirect but I usually prefer to have an option to switch it off and on when needed. The 301 should be cached and tells the client to not use the original URL in the future. I don't usually use 307 and 308 because I don't want the POST/PUT/DELETE etc. to work with redirects for security reasons - I don't want potentially sensitive data to be sent, get redirect and be sent again securely. I want that case to break and to force methods other than GET to use the HTTPS explicitly. For me the redirect is mostly for browsers but your mileage may vary.